# SQL ORDER BY statement for dates

Tags: python, sql, database, psycopg2

I developed a Python program that reads an Excel file, performs operations on it and uploads information into a database using the psycopg2 package and SQL statements.
These SQL statements are stored in a list and are executed by using a for loop:

```
def my_method_results_quant_rsk(input_data_frame, database_data_frame):
    combination_set = set()
    sql_querys_results_quant_rsk = []

    for index, row in database_data_frame.iterrows():
        temp_string = str(row["reference_date"]) + str(row["risk_category"]) + \
                      str(row["risk_subcategory"]) + str(row["source"])
        temp_string = ''.join(temp_string.split())
        combination_set.add(temp_string)

    for index, row in input_data_frame.iterrows():
        temp_string = str(row["date"]) + str(row["category"]) + str(row["subcategory"]) + str(row["source"])
        temp_string = ''.join(temp_string.split())

        reference_date = row['date']
        risk_category = row['category']
        risk_subcategory = row['subcategory']
        source = row['source']
        cap_limit = row['limit']
        cap_requirement = row['riskCap']
        percentage = row['percentage']

        if temp_string in combination_set:
            sql_query_results_quant_rsk_1 = f"UPDATE results_quant_rsk SET cap_limit = '{cap_limit}' WHERE reference_date = '{reference_date}' AND risk_category = '{risk_category}' AND risk_subcategory = '{risk_subcategory}' AND source = '{source}';"
            sql_query_results_quant_rsk_2 = f"UPDATE results_quant_rsk SET cap_requirement = '{cap_requirement}' WHERE reference_date = '{reference_date}' AND risk_category = '{risk_category}' AND risk_subcategory = '{risk_subcategory}' AND source = '{source}';"
            sql_query_results_quant_rsk_3 = f"UPDATE results_quant_rsk SET percentage = '{percentage}' WHERE reference_date = '{reference_date}' AND risk_category = '{risk_category}' AND risk_subcategory = '{risk_subcategory}' AND source = '{source}';"
            sql_querys_results_quant_rsk.append(sql_query_results_quant_rsk_1)
            sql_querys_results_quant_rsk.append(sql_query_results_quant_rsk_2)
            sql_querys_results_quant_rsk.append(sql_query_results_quant_rsk_3)
        else:
            sql_query_results_quant_rsk = f"INSERT INTO results_quant_rsk(reference_date, risk_category, risk_subcategory, source, cap_limit, cap_requirement, percentage) VALUES('{reference_date}', '{risk_category}', '{risk_subcategory}', '{source}', '{cap_limit}', '{cap_requirement}', '{percentage}');"
            sql_querys_results_quant_rsk.append(sql_query_results_quant_rsk)

    return sql_querys_results_quant_rsk
```

The list created in the above method is then executed:

```
for sql in sqls_results_quant_rsk:
    my_cursor.execute(sql)
```

The execution works perfectly fine. However, afterwards I need to order the data table by date which is not working for some reason. The table is called "results_quant_rsk" and the column with the dates is called "reference_date" of the type **date NOT NULL**. I tried:

```
my_cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM results_quant_rsk ORDER BY reference_date;")
```

Below you can see the rows of the "reference_date" column that are obviously not ordered...

```
"2021-07-31"
"2021-07-31"
"2021-07-31"
"2021-07-31"
"2021-07-31"
"2021-07-31"
"2021-07-31"
"2021-07-31"
"2021-08-31"
"2021-08-31"
"2021-08-31"
"2021-08-31"
"2021-08-31"
"2021-08-31"
"2021-08-31"
"2021-08-31"
"2021-08-31"
"2021-09-30"
"2021-10-31"
"2021-09-30"
"2021-09-30"
"2021-09-30"
"2021-09-30"
"2021-09-30"
"2021-09-30"
"2021-09-30"
"2021-09-30"
```

Instead it should be ordered in ascending order.

Comment: You're executing multiple queries in a loop. Are these the results of one query or all of them? Because each one will start over from the beginning.

Comment: I am executing multiple queries that either add an entry to the database or update an existing entry. What do you mean by "each one will start over from the beginning"?

Comment: I was guessing that the output you show is the result of multiple SELECT queries. Each one is ordered properly, but when you look at the combined results they aren't.

Comment: To make sure this does not happen, the order statement is not executed in the for loop but afterwards. I also tried to tried to close the cursor and commit all the update changes and then open the cursor again, execute the order statement and commit this once more... Did not do the trick....

Comment: I can't think of any other explanation. A single query should not get the order wrong like that.

Comment: That is what makes me so clueless

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle that demonstrates the problem? There's not enough here to go by.

Comment: Understandable... unfortunately I am not allowed to do that. Anyways, thanks for your effort!

Comment: If you can't provide a [mre], we're not going to be able to solve this.

Comment: The SQL fiddle would not give any insight that could help to solve the problem. When executing the order statement directly in SQL in the database, it works. But when executing it from the python program it does not... Seems like something is wrong with the order in which the statements are executed. However, if I close the cursor, commit everything and reopen it again to execute the order statements, they should be executed lastly right? I added some insights into the python program... Maybe this helps.

Comment: Python doesn't reorder the results of a query when you fetch the results. So something else must be going on. There's nothing we can see in the qustion that can possibly help us figure out what this is.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the certain `ASC|DESC` which will sort your reference date by ascending order. If you need it in descending order, try `DESC|ASC`.

```
my_cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM results_quant_rsk ORDER BY reference_date ASC | DESC;")
```

Alternatively, you can also try:

```
my_cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM resutls_quant_rsk ORDER BY Year(reference_date), month(reference_date);")
```

Which will take a `year` from `reference_date` and a `month` from `reference_date` to order the corresponding date.

Comment: I've edited your answer to improve your formatting. Please review so that, in the future, you can apply similar formatting to your answers. That improves the readability, and makes them more useful to future readers.

Comment: I tried both of your solutions. Unfortunately when running the first alternative, the database remains in the same order. For the second alternative I get the following error: 
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: function year(date) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM results_qual_rsk ORDER BY Year(reference_date)...
                                                ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: Can you please send me the screenshot of it

Comment: I would love to but I do not know how to send privat messages here. Also I cannot attach a Screenshot to a comment... :D

Comment: `ASC` is the default, you don't need to specify it explicitly.